Can I use "Britons" in data reports?
Maybe it's just me, but I mostly see people using "British people" or "the British" instead of "Britons". Therefore, I wonder if Britons is used in data reports. For example:

The number of Britons falling into the 30-to-40 age group has increased.


What do you mean? Britain is not the same as the United Kingdom, although British is commonly used for both. If you've already stated what geographical area you've covered it might be OK for variety, but using an even vaguer term like Briton won't help make your writing any clearer.

It depends on your context. You need to stress this is for business or economics, just like many of your other questions. Here's the thing though: falling is not great there. Categories of people may fall into some range but here, you can just do away with it: The number of British people in the 30-to-40 age group has risen.

the who? :-D
https://youtu.be/iZP5Cie7K1g?si=Qc36faUCASh_XJ8o&t=81

A friend who had a temp job at the Home Office, in a section concerned with nationality, told me the staff casually referred to UK nationals as 'Brit-cits'.

@MichaelHarvey Standard UK passports typically say "Nationality: British citizen" (assuming the person does not have a different status such as British Overseas Territory Citizen or British Protected Person  etc.).

If this is a technical report you should stick to precise and unambiguous terms. As many others have said, this can get tricky, and cause offence in certain quarters. First you need to decide what you mean. I do not know what is meant by Britons in this sentence, it could be many things.

It depends on what time period your data report is about.

Sure, if you want.  There's nothing pejorative or insulting about the word "Britons".  However "British people" is probably more common.
Remember the issues about naming of nationalities.  Not all Britons are English (many Scots and Welsh). Not everyone living in the UK is a Briton (many Irish).  Moreover, many British people are immigrants or the descendants of immigrants. "Briton" is sometimes used (in context) to mean the people that were living on the island 2000 years ago, before the English arrived from the continent.

Is there any word for people living in the UK, including Irish people?

@anIELTSlearner - there is a phrase- 'UK residents'. Not everything in life is simple enough to be expressed in one word.

You don't even need to add "people". You can refer to "the British", and it would be perfectly acceptable to abbreviate a label in something like a report to simply "British".

This OP is doing economics charts. So, it isn't all the same. British people is probably better for that.

@anIELTSlearner It depends on how precise or literal you want to be.  Athletes from Northern Ireland are part of "Team GB" even though it's not actually correct. If you are speaking in general terms then "British people" is probably okay, even if some UK residents are not "British".

I've seen ‘UKians’ in very informal cases; I don't think it's well-known, but the meaning should be fairly clear.

@phuzi: Then you can say "UK citizens" or "British citizens" (don't say "British subjects," because apparently it's complicated).

@phuzi - the phrase 'UK residents' was my answer to the OP, who additionally asked, in a comment, Is there any word for people living in the UK, including Irish people?. Please explain the reason for your comment.

"The British" is possibly more idiomatic than "British people". Just don't say "Brits", which seems to have crept in fairly recently possibly from Australian usage.

@MichaelHarvey Sorry, I must have missed that, comment retracted.

@MarkMorganLloyd - the Seppos also say 'Brit' a lot; we don't mind that much, although it gets old quite quickly; it's a lot less offensive than 'Limey faggot', or 'whinging Pom', come to that.

There was a brilliant comedy play, and later a film, called No Sex Please, We're British.

This is an excellent answer for informal usage.  For a data report, though, all these terms — “Britons”, “the British”, “British people”, etc — are quite imprecise and ambiguous; they could mean “UK residents”, “UK citizens”, “residents of Great Britain”, “residents of the British Isles”, or more.  So for an actual data report, it’s best to give a more precise description, like “UK residents” etc.

@Kevin 'British citizens' can also be ambiguous for the same reason as 'British subjects' - the terminology changed along with laws and political circumstances, plus 'British' itself is ambiguous (Does it include the Irish? The Bretons? The Manx? The whole Commonwealth? All the people of the former empire? Just the white ones?). They are both defined in current law, of course, but the legal definitions don't always match colloquial use, or even use in other parts of the law.

@MichaelHarvey At the same time, despite being an ethnic Welshman if somebody asked me where my loyalties lay I'd say "Britain". Similarly, it's traditionally the "British Army" in colloquial speech, not "the UKish" or anything like that.

This expands a bit on James K's answer. It turns out that the OP picked a particularly complex example.
Technically, Great Britain is the bigger island on the right side of the photo below from the Wikipedia article.

That is, it is the island containing the nations of England, Wales, and Scotland. Ireland is not Great Britain. The island of Ireland is on the left (partly shown). Northern Ireland is part of the United Kingdom, as are England, Wales, and Scotland. The Republic of Ireland was part of the UK until 1922. The vast majority of citizens very strongly prefer not to be part of the UK. For that matter, I think a significant minority of Northern Irish share this opinion.
For interest, the full name of the UK is the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. This blogger offered the following diagram to illustrate the relationships:

The Wikipedia page for the UK lists British, Briton, and Brit as acceptable demonyms for residents of the entire UK. A demonym is the word that identifies a group of people in a particular place, like Americans as residents of the US - although people in Mexico and Latin America do have substantive reasons to object to that term (Mexico being part of North America, Latin America being most of South America).
The UK is also unusual in that the people of the UK consider themselves to come from different nations, e.g. England, Wales, Scotland, and Northern Ireland. I think that most other countries don't think of nations being part of the larger country, although perhaps they should (e.g. the US has many Native American nations, the Russian Federation has many semi-autonomous ethnic republics, the Soviet Union had Russia plus several other conquered states that definitely had their own ethnic/national identities). Most people probably think of minority races or ethnic groups rather than separate nations. The formal of the word nation is a community of people formed on the basis of a common language, territory, ethnicity. Most nations have their own country. Some do not (can be called stateless nations, e.g. Kurds, Basques). Most ordinary English speakers would probably consider nation to be roughly synonymous with state, and they might not know what to make of the formal term nation state (opposite of a stateless nation; not all states are nation states, e.g. the US).
How should outsiders navigate this type of situation? You can most likely stick to the most commonly used terms in official reports or major news outlets. Be generally aware that there may be conflicts depending on the country's history. If confronted, plead ignorance as a non-native English speaker. As you develop more familiarity, I would try to use the most inclusive demonym. If a term is dated, don't use it until you're more familiar with the political situation. Be aware that the preferred term may change, although that change will tend to be contested.
Most definitely avoid using English when you are referring to all residents of the UK. After initially writing this, I realize that the Mandarin Chinese (I'm a heritage speaker) name for Britain is 英国 (yīng guó), which is also the Mandarin name for England. I'm not sure if the distinction between the English and British is clear in all languages. Generally, people are likely to be more accepting of mistakes like this if they can tell you are not a native speaker of English. However, you can't always tell when writing online.

To your last paragraph: while it’s quite common to hear 英国 used for the UK (the same way it’s not uncommon to hear ‘England’ used for the UK outside the British Isles), the more accurate name for the country of England is 英格兰 Yīnggélán. Like the words for Wales (威尔士 Wēi’ěrshì) and Scotland (苏格兰 Sūgélán), 英格兰 is perfectly common in conversation; conversely, I must admit I’ve never heard the name for Britain (不列颠 Bùlièdiān) in regular conversation.

As this is a data report, you might want to look at the Administrative Data Research UK style guide (pdf). It states (p10):

Use British and Britons rather than Brits. However, there is a preference for "those living in the UK" to avoid exclusion [of people living in Northern Ireland].

The Guardian style guide states similarly that Britons is fine (and not Brits):

Brits: avoid using except when quoting people; Britons or British people should be used.

The Economist Style Guide (quite a large pdf) does not make any explicit reference but it uses the word Britons:

British titles: Long incomprehensible to all foreigners and most
Britons, British titles and forms of address now seem just as confusing to those who hold them.

I think they are actually eliding the British/UK distinction here, as there are titled UK citizens of areas outside Britain, notably the Northern Ireland members of the House of Lords.
In any case, the overall message seems to be that Britons is fine in formal writing, if it accurately refers to the group you intend. The Cambridge Guide to English Usage states re Britons, In spite of historical overtones, it seems to be regaining ground as a general appellation.
